# top.frames is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using two `iframes` in my page
the parent page have a `iframe` say `id = grandparent , src = "child.html".`

and in child.html i am setting some variables and also there is a `iframe` in child.html say

```
id = parent, src="grandchild.html"
```

and from grandchild.html i am accessing the variable in child.html using the JavaScript

```
var value = top.frames['grandparent']
```

It is working fine in chrome but not working in firefox means with the value variable i am not able to access the variable of child.html

please help

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox behavior is the one the spec calls for.  See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#dom-window-nameditem-filter and the rules for browsing context names at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element

WebKit has a known bug (see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11388 ) where it turns the iframe's id into the name of the window inside.

For your case, you just want to use `name="grandparent"` on the relevant iframe.

Comment: I was also facing the same problem. Your solution helped me. Thanks.